# Navigator.pop(context) throws exception

Tags: android, dart, flutter, drawer, navigator

I was trying to achieve an UI which has both drawer and a TabBar demo , for this I tried following:-

```
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new NewApp());

class NewApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          drawer: Drawer(
            child: ListView(

              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: <Widget>[
                DrawerHeader(
                  child: Text("Drawer Header"),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text("Item1"),
                  onTap: (){
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text("Item2"),
                  onTap: (){
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),

              ],
            ),
          ),
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.room),text: "Room",),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.restaurant),text: "Restaurant",),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.school),text: "School"),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text("Tab Bar View + Drawer"),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.room),
              Icon(Icons.restaurant),
              Icon(Icons.school),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
     }
     }
```

Now this gives me an error:-
             Another exception was thrown: Navigator operation requested with a 
             context that does not include a Navigator.

Please help clearing it if anyone has solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't the reason for the error/fix(which I made and which worked). Somebody, please explain how it works. I simply wrapped the `DefaultTabController` into another stateless widget `Home`. It works fine. Please refer to the code below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new NewApp());

class NewApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(

            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              DrawerHeader(
                child: Text("Drawer Header"),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text("Item1"),
                onTap: (){
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text("Item2"),
                onTap: (){
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.room),text: "Room",),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.restaurant),text: "Restaurant",),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.school),text: "School"),
            ],
          ),
          title: Text("Tab Bar View + Drawer"),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            Icon(Icons.room),
            Icon(Icons.restaurant),
            Icon(Icons.school),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
    // TODO: implement build
  }

}
```